# Image toggle on click(function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, toggle

I have a block of javascript code which moves #slidingDiv down on toggle. Is there anyway I can add a swap image into this? I need an image with the name #clicktoggleimage to swap between images "/images/show-less-arrow.jpg" and "/images/show-more-arrow.jpg" in the same function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#slidingDiv").hide();
$(".show_hide").show();

$('.show_hide').click(function() {
    $("#slidingDiv").slideToggle(500);
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#slidingDiv").offset().top + $('window').height()
    }, 1000);
});
});

</script>
```

Many thanks

Pete

Comment: Pete, you should look into image maps for this sort of this http://www.noobcube.com/tutorials/html-css/css-image-maps-a-beginners-guide-/ The problem here is, you'll always get some delays when using separate images, but with one image, once it's loaded, you're good to go and switch as much as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle the image's `src` like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var image = document.getElementById('clicktoggleimage');

    $("#slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function() {
        $("#slidingDiv").slideToggle(500);
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#slidingDiv").offset().top + $('window').height()
        }, 1000);
        // New code here:
        image.src = (image.src.indexOf('show-more') > -1")
            ? image.src.replace("show-more", "show-less")
            : image.src.replace("show-less", "show-more");
    });
});
```

(The `? :` bit is a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#JavaScript), shorthand for:)

```
if(image.src == "/images/show-less-arrow.jpg"){
    image.src = "/images/show-more-arrow.jpg"
}else{
    image.src = "/images/show-less-arrow.jpg"
}
```

**Edit:**

The `src` will now be changed depending on if the current `src` contains `'show-more'`, or not. If it does, `'show-more'` is replaced with `'show-less'`, and vice versa.

**Or,**

[Take a look at sprites.](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)

Comment: This may result in loading/flicker problems. It would probably be a better idea to use an image map. Not a critique of your input, just a comment on overall issue.

Comment: Hi there It doesn't seem to work. IS my HTML correct?  <a href="<?php echo WEB_URL; ?>#show" class="show_hide">
 <img src="<?php echo WEB_URL; ?>/images/show-less-arrow.jpg" width="61" height="45" name="clicktoggleimage" />
</a>

Comment: @mkey: image map? Don't you mean [sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)? You're right though.

Comment: @PeteNaylor: Ah, there's more to your `src` than mentioned at first, lemme see what I can do.

Comment: Isn't that a "potato-patata" type of thing?

Comment: @mkey: Not really, usually, maps refer [to this].(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/map)

Comment: @mkey, the top 5 links link to a tutorial on how to make something happen, when you mouseover a certain area of a image. That's related to what the <map> tag used to do. They happen to use sprites, nowadays, since that doesn't mean sprites are called image maps.

I mean, just look at the [definition](https://www.google.nl/search?q=image+map) [of "image map"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map)

Comment: I find this to be a straw man argument and I simply don't have time for those. I have been using that term for a while now (in various programming technologies) and I was unable to cause confusion by doing that. Yet.

Answer (score 0):

what I would suggest is to use `jQuery.toggleClass()` to toggle a CSS class on an element. then define the CSS to use a sprite as a background-image on that element. you could write JavaScript to swap images, but this way is cleaner and in the end, easier.

```
$('.show_hide').click(function() {

    // add this
    $(this).toggleClass("isShown");

    $("#slidingDiv").slideToggle(500);
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#slidingDiv").offset().top + $('window').height()
    }, 1000);
});
```

CSS

```
.show_hide {
    background: url('images/showHideSprite.png') no-repeat 0px 0px;
}

.show_hide.isShown {
    /* change offset on sprite to show only the "shown" image */
    background-position: 20px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using attribute

**HTML**

```
<img id="foo" src="/../img/logo.png">
<button id="btn">Flip</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
    $("#foo").attr("src", function(a,b){ 
        return (b === "/../img/logo.png") ? "http://www.google.com/textinputassistant/tia.png" : "/../img/logo.png";
    }); 
});​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AY2xX/

Answer (score 0):

You can update the src attribute of the image in your click function.  Something like this should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#slidingDiv").hide();
$(".show_hide").show();

$('.show_hide').click(function() {

    var srcless "/images/show-less-arrow.jpg";
    var srcmore = "/images/show-more-arrow.jpg";

    if($('#clicktoggleimage').attr("src") == srcless){
        $('#clicktoggleimage').attr("src",srcmore);
    }else{
        $('#clicktoggleimage').attr("src",srcless)
    }

    $("#slidingDiv").slideToggle(500);

    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#slidingDiv").offset().top + $('window').height()
    }, 1000);
});
});

</script>
```